# What does the $j$ mean in this notation?

Tags: electromagnetism, notation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

This section of Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by Griffiths is talking about the Maxwell Stress Tensor. I don't quite understand what the $j$ means on the left side of the "$=$" sign (for either of the 2 representations).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It means the jth component of the term inside the parentheses, which is a vector with three components.

Answer (score 0):

The $j$ represents the $j$-th component like is mentioned above. Seeing as your question is really about confusion about index notation rather than than the actual quantum mechanics, let me suggest a book to you. There is an incredible amount of books that will deal with vector and tensor notation across all different fields and subject types. The one I found that really cemented index gymnastics and notation was Tensors, Relativity and cosmology - Dalarsson & Dalarsson.

This might be because it's a great book or because it was probably my 4th or 5th time trying to get my head around it.

If I were you, I'd get a good strong mental capacity for the notation and index gymnastics before jumping into a book on  QM.

Two more are Goldstein - Mechanics. Landau - Mechanics Vol I in series.

Cheers.